# Prove that for any $S \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ and functions $f,g : S \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$ $f$ is homotopic to $g$.

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification, homotopy-theory

Prove that for any $S \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ and functions $f,g : S \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$ we have $f \sim g$. (Here by $f \sim g$ I mean f is homotopic to $g$).

Here is my attempt at a proof:

Let $h : S \times I \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$ be given by,
$$h(x,t)=(1-t)f(x)+tg(x)$$

Then since $h(x,0)=(1-0)f(x)+0\cdot g(x)=f(x)$ and $h(x,1)=(1-1)f(x)+1 \cdot g(x)=g(x)$ the function $h$ is a homotopy between $f$ and $g$ for any $f,g : S \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$.

I have two questions about this proof:

1. Is the above function $h$ in fact a homotopy between $f$ and $g$? I thought that only two continuous functions can be homotopic to each other, but $f$ and $g$ are not defined to be continuous.
2. Is there any necessity for this problem only to refer to functions between two Euclidean spaces?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$(1)$: In algebraic topology, maps are often *assumed* to be **continuous**, without explicitly mentioning so.

$(2)$: You are using the convexity of $\mathbb R^n$ for $n\ge 1$. So, you can use the same argument for any convex space.